# How to abort the request execution from GetPageItemProcessor (Sitecore 8.2)

Tags: pipelines

How to abort the execution of the whole request and redirect to another page from `GetPageItemProcessor` Sitecore `pipeline processor`. I tried a few options but they all make the execution of the request continues to the rendering controller of the item requested.
I used:

```
WebUtil.Redirect(smsRedirectUrl, false);
WebUtil.Redirect(smsRedirectUrl, true);
```

I also tried to use "return" with no luck

Comment: Can you share the code snippet you have implemented. As this is a pipeline, normally, you can use args.AbortPipeline(). This will stop the execution of the pipeline

Comment: Thanks Hishaam for your response.
"you can use args.AbortPipeline()"
That's right but I don't want to just abort the pipeline I need to stop the execution of the whole request. After the pipeline, the controllers of the renderings on the target item get executed

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/15088/stop-executing-remaining-processor-of-a-pipeline